# Counting letter "r" in Django queryset

Tags: django, count, django-queryset

I need to count all "r"s in field 'wertung' in a queryset.

"right = protokoll.filter(wertung__contains ='r').count()" -
counts the fields containing a "r" - no matter if there is one "r" or two "rr",
but now I need to count all "r"s.

Comment: @psky : Thank you!It worked - a bit.  The code seems to count all "r"s in all fields in the queryset (filter(wertung__contains ='r')), but I only need the "r"s in "wertung". In between I worked thru the reference and tried to understand it  ... but I did not manage to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To count all occurrences of the letter "r" in the "wertung" field across all records in the queryset, you can use the annotate() function in combination with the Count() function.

```
from django.db.models import Count, Sum, Q


r_count = Protokoll.objects.annotate(r_count=Count('wertung', filter=Q(wertung__contains='r'))).aggregate(total_r_count=Sum('r_count'))['total_r_count']
```

For reference please see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd fetch the data from fields containing 'r' and then generate the count in Python.

```
data = protokoll.filter(wertung__contains ='r').values_list('wertung', flat=True)
r_count = 0
for value in data:
    r_count += value.count('r')
```